# Genre of soundtrack music for small remote desert towns?

Tags: identify-this-genre

Imagine a movie scene situated at a god-forsaken town out in the middle of nowhere. Usually it is somewhere in the Western United States. Typically, you'd see some old gas station, or even a cow skull alongside the dusty road.

In many cases, the vocal instrument sounds like playing a guitar with a bottleneck slide. Sometimes a harmonica is also included.

The long intro to the song [*Bad Seamstress Blues, Fallin' Apart At The Seams*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mKvxq-xiZ_8) by [Cinderella](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cinderella_(band)) is a good example (before it turns into heavy metal).

What is the name of this musical genre?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's some good ol' **country blues**.  Compare these examples (literally the first two that came up in a search for that term on YouTube):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J-kH82K8dCs

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WsqTkkUzH5w

Country blues is a direct descendant of the original folk and rural blues styles that represented an early American adaption of African musical styles and aesthetics, via African-American communities in the rural South. The adaption of folk blues to urban big bands was the birth of jazz.  A generation or so later, an electrified urban version of the blues was the direct forerunner of rock and roll.

The original style was absorbed into the country-western music tradition, and has come to be a common soundtrack shorthand to indicate a sleepy rural or Western town.  (See [this question](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/2277/oh-we-got-both-kinds-we-got-country-and-western-but-whats-actually-the-diff) for more about the much wider *Country-Western* genre.)  Although folk blues was originally an African-American style, it's rarely heard these days outside of the predominantly white country-western genre, where it is frequently incorporated into country rock.

Comment: Country-Western is a much larger genre that represents a wide range of rural styles over the years.  Country blues is the adoption of the old folk blues style into the Country-Western genre.  Although folk blues was originally an African-American style, it's rarely heard these days outside of the predominantly white country-western genre.

Comment: Also, "Country-Western" is a Billboard genre (see [this question](http://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/1026/why-do-music-genres-exist)), it is tied to audience, and represents the way the music industry tracks sales and conceptualizes promotions.  "Country blues" is an unofficial descriptor based on the evolution of a particular sub-genre and its specific musical characteristics.

Comment: Funny enough, not long ago I watched a video of the same dude from your first link playing a shovel with strings, which I thought was brilliant. I couldn't remember what it was called so I didn't put it in the original question, but [here it is](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V9-ltPsbw9g)  just in case anyone will ever wanna watch this...

Answer (score 2):

This is often called [Western music](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Western_music_(North_America)), so named because of its connotations with the western United States (not the Western hemisphere). It's also occasionally called "Cowboy" music.

Comment: I don't think this is specific enough.  "Western music" typically refers to the old cowboy styles --[Gene Autry](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=80NoPLp-Zl0) and [Roy Rogers](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WLoYFvbR0XY).  That has a very different sound from the referenced track.