# Guitar riff that forms the first 10 seconds of Little Barrie's "I Can't Wait"

Tags: identify-this-song, cover, guitar

I recently listened to [Little Barrie's *I Can't Wait*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ejxO15Ok4F4) from their album King of the wave.

In the first few seconds there is a guitar part that just sounds awesome. But it also stops right after 10 seconds. I want to know if this part is a cover or a sample of an older song. And if not where I could find similar music (genre,band) to the first 10 seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a fairly standard electric guitar riff, and unlikely to be a sample or a cover.  Your best bet on finding similar music is to look for *electric blues* or *[blues rock](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tVSMABmTo_U)*.  It sounds like this riff is using [a slide](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NW08Rc802MQ), so you might add that into your search.  Compare, for example, this recent [electric blues](https://youtu.be/lXlvJQl5xLI?t=1m50s&list=PLzAkvMLHpcrxBMnvbRRimX5z00PpSubzy) piece by Gary Clark Jr. (there's a long section near the beginning which is all one note, but then it goes into a section very much like your clip).

Blues is a primarily African-American style of music with a strong connection to the musical styles of West Africa.  Here in the United States it developed out of the repetitive choral work songs used by (primarily black) sharecroppers, chain-gang prisoners and railroad workers.  WC Handy, an African-American musicologist, developed it into a popular style based on the use of "blue notes," which approximated notes from West African scales not found in European music.

Blues developed both into a rural acoustic form called "country blues" that influenced country music and later country rock (see [this question](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/4426/genre-of-soundtrack-music-for-small-remote-desert-towns/4428#4428)), and an electrified urban form that was a direct ancestor of early rock and roll.  Another infusion of blues into rock came via British invasion bands such as [the Beatles](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fYvfLGYDpRQ), the [Rolling Stones](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PVZH7IdHP2E&list=PLJvzTkgdy4835_-vIPBt6wmfLBkeQDML5) and [Led Zepplin](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zyhu2ysqKGk), all of whom idolized blues musicians like [Muddy Waters](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oHowqKYSXNI) and [B. B. King](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-Y8QxOjuYHg).  Blues-inspired rock guitar riffs remain common across many styles of modern rock.