# Genre of two songs

Tags: genre, electronic-music, pop, genre-characteristics

The genre of [*Love Yourself*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oyEuk8j8imI) by [Justin Bieber](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Justin_Bieber) is Dance/Electronic. But the genre of [*Dancing On My Own*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q31tGyBJhRY) by [Calum Scott](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calum_Scott) is Pop.

They both are a bit sad and go slowly. So why are they considered different genres?

Comment: [Welcome to Music Fans Stack Exchange](http://musicfans.stackexchange.com/tour). Please clarify what have you tried. Here you can learn [how you can improve your question](http://meta.musicfans.stackexchange.com/a/368/1721) 
and increase your chances for find the music you're looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got the same results as you when I googled [Love Yourself Justin Bieber genre](https://www.google.com/search?q=love%20yourself%20justin%20bieber%20genre) and [Dancing On My Own Calum Scott genre](https://www.google.com/search?q=dancing%20on%20my%20own%20calum%20scott%20genre), which is where I'm going to assume you got those songs' genres from.

However, when I went to the Wikipedia pages for the songs, both "[Love Yourself](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Love_Yourself)" and "[Dancing On My Own](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dancing_On_My_Own#Calum_Scott_version)" have a genre of *Acoustic Pop*.

In addition, AllMusic said that both "[Love Yourself](http://www.allmusic.com/album/love-yourself-mw0002897540)" and "[Dancing On My Own](http://www.allmusic.com/album/dancing-on-my-own-mw0002953142)" have a genre of *Pop/Rock*.

According to iTunes, they're both *Pop*. And Discogs says they're both *Pop* too. And so does Genius.

So what's the takeaway here? Well, it could be one of a few things.

#### Google is wrong.

Certainly a possibility, as none of these other sources seems to say that the genre of "Love Yourself" is Electronic *or* Dance.

#### Maybe genres are, in a lot of ways, meaningless?

[This excellent answer](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/a/1039/431) on another question on this site details the history of genres, and how they were created for marketing purposes and to segregate artists by race. And this [other excellent answer](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/a/2702/431) describes the difference between Soul, Funk, and R&B as genres and how some artists identified as "Funk" bands but no artists really identified as "R&B" bands.

In this case, Google is probably wrong, but it's definitely good to keep in mind that the genre a specific website, record label, radio station, or magazine might put on a song might be completely different from what genre a similar entity (or even the artist themselves) might put on the song.