# Artists similar to Linkin Park, Breaking Benjamin, Evanescence, Fireflight, Within Temptation, Red, Trading Yesterday, Three Days Grace

Tags: rock, identify-this-genre, similar-artists

I'm a music enthusiast but have a hard time classifying sub-genres. So I wanted to ask what genre do you think I am into. The reason I'm asking is that I'd like to explore other artists of the same genre.

Here are some of the bands I admire: Linkin Park, Breaking Benjamin, Evanescence, Fireflight, Within Temptation, Red, Trading Yesterday, Three Days Grace. Of these bands, I've listened to almost all of the tracks exclusively, and needless to mention I've loved all of them.

It's easy to derive that I am into rock. But what's bothering me is the sub-genre. I mean, all of the bands have a variety of sub-genres: alternative rock, gothic rock, symphonic metal, nu metal, Christian rock, alternative metal and hard rock to name a few.

I'm quite confident that I'm not into heavy metal as I've tried Metallica and Iron Maiden, but didn't like most of their songs. But I did love their guitar solos (for e.g. Master of Puppets, Stairway to Heaven, etc.).

Regarding the types of songs I prefer, I have two phases.

Sometimes I prefer a bit violent and strong type of rock characterised by guitars and intensive bass and drums, for e.g. Linkin Park - In the End and 
[Breaking Benjamin - The Diary of Jane](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DWaB4PXCwFU).

At other times I really prefer the quiet versions depicting an element of sadness through the music. Most of the rock bands have at least one such, for e.g. [Evanescence - My Immortal](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5anLPw0Efmo) and [Red - Pieces](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8Uw8mIcQJn8).

If you'd ask me to select which ones I like more amongst them, I'd select the latter.

So what would you classify my sub genre as? Also after classifying the genre, which artists / tracks would you suggest to me?

Comment: Hi. Welcome. As it is written right now, your question seems too broad, and will likely be closed. I suggest you try to rewrite it and add some more bounds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specifying better, your genre is between Nu metal and Gothic metal.

Usually we wake up willing to listen to a quieter song, sometimes something louder, this is normal, so it is very difficult to hold on to a genre only, when we hear something derived from Heavy metal, with a more current footprint without escaping the traditional weight, we call it
Nu Metal, where they fit elements of Hip Hop like Linkin Park, and electronic traces like Three Days Grace, all of this is part of something broader like Alternative Metal/Rock.

As for Evanescence and derivatives, there are no doubts that fit in the Gothic Metal.

Answer (score 1):

As [this question](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/1026/why-do-music-genres-exist) indicates, genres are largely created and defined in one of two ways, either as a marketing move, in order to target an audience, by labels and music charts, or (typically before being discovered by the mainstream) as the innovations of a tight-knit group of musicians and fans who interact with and inspire each other.  Many people, however, enjoy music of multiple genres.  So there's no particular reason to expect that your own personal music tastes will define a particular sub-genre that is meaningful to anyone else.

From just a quick glance at your list of choices, it looks like your best way of summarizing it is with one of the more general, less tightly focused genres, probably hard rock.  You probably can't get much more specific than that without starting to lose favorites of yours.  However, there's a very long tradition of hard rockers producing the occasional ballad, so that's also a fit.

As far as recommendations, it seems like your choices are all relatively recent, maybe check out some older hard rock groups that first created this sound, like [Led Zeppelin](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n6fBQRaygeo), or early [Aerosmith](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hHRNSeuvzlM). I know you said you weren't a big Metallica fan, but you might try just looking for [their ballads](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=waBb-UM5m4g) even if you don't like their more metal side.  On the other hand, it might be that it's a specifically a more contemporary sound you're looking for.  In that case, I'm not the person who can give you much help, but you might try searching for "[new hard rock](http://www.vh1.com/news/222970/hard-rock-new-bands/)". The relatively recent [Ayreon](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LBgTiLMTlxo) might also be a good fit for your interests.